# Using Modules in Python, but can't seem to get the loop to display the distance the vehicle has traveled for each hour of a time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm a beginner programmer and I understand how to do this program without modules, but we're told to build off previous assignments and continue practice modular programming. I'm having a hard time with my printDistance module. It isn't displaying each hour and the distance traveled per hour.

Thanks for the help,

Darryl

```
   #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Name:         Darryl Lardizabal
    # Date:         3-12-2017
    # Reference:    Chapter 5     page #225 problem # 6
    # Title:    Distance Traveled
    # Constants:    
    # Inputs:   vehicleSpeed, hoursTraveled.
    # Process:  Calculating speed and time to figure out distance traveled per hour.
    # Outputs:  Distance traveled for each hour of that time period. 
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    vehicleSpeed = 0
    hoursTraveled = 0
    distanceTraveled = 0

    ##---Introductory Statement: Welcome to the Program---------------------------------------------#
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def intro():
        print("\n".join(["---------------------------------------------------------",
                  "Hello and Welcome to the Distance Travled Program",
                  "Get ready to find out how far you traveled per hour!",
                  "---------------------------------------------------------"]))
        return

    ##---The getSpeed module gets speed of vehicle to help calculate distance traveled/hr-----------#
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def getSpeed(): 
        vehicleSpeed=int(input("Please enter your average speed in mph: "))
        return vehicleSpeed

    ##---The getHours mod. gets the # of hours traveled to help calculate distance traveled/hr------#
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def getHours(): 
        hoursTraveled=int(input("Please enter the number of hours you traveled in mph: "))
        return hoursTraveled

    ##-The calculateDistance mod. calculates distance traveled/hr using inputs for speed and hours--#
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def calculateDistance(vehicleSpeed, hoursTraveled):
        distanceTraveled = vehicleSpeed * hoursTraveled
        return distanceTraveled

    ##-The printDistance mod. displays distance traveled for each hour of the user's time period----#
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def printDistance(vehicleSpeed, hoursTraveled, distanceTraveled):
        print("---------------------------------")
        print(" Hour\tDistance")
        print("---------------------------------")
        for hourTraveled in range(1, hoursTraveled+1):
            print(hoursTraveled,"\t",hoursTraveled*vehicleSpeed)
        return 



    #---Run main module-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def main():
        intro()
        getSpeed()
        getHours()
        calculateDistance(vehicleSpeed, hoursTraveled)
        printDistance(vehicleSpeed, hoursTraveled, distanceTraveled)

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with 'hourTraveled' and 'hoursTraveled'.

I think you meant to use hourTraveled when you used hour**s**Traveled. This should fix your issue I think.

```
    for hourTraveled in range(1, hoursTraveled+1):
        print(hourTraveled,"\t",hourTraveled*vehicleSpeed)
    return
```

Comment: fixed the hourTraveled, actually used the hoursTraveled variable, but still not setting up the table format yet.